# Android transferring data from free to paid version

Tags: android, json, copy, sharedpreferences, android-contentprovider

For my app, all of its data is saved in a JSON file and a SharedPreferences. If a user buys the paid app after using the free app, what is the best way to copy over the JSON file/SharedPreferences from the free app to the paid app?

Comment: You might want to consider [in-app billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html), i.e., buying the upgrade from within the app itself instead of having two different versions of the app in the Market.

Answer (score 0):

make your free app store it somewhere in the SD card and then read it from the paid app!

Comment: So what about phones/tablets that don't accept SD cards? None of my test devices use SD cards.

Comment: they do have internal storage accessible to the user if not the SD card. see this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: @NirajAdhikari Internal storage is not shared between apps, so the files of one app cannot be access by a different app.

Comment: ContentProviders should be the way to go then..by internal storage i meant like one present in a embedded storage like on a galaxy sii / siii that acts like a external storage but embedded into a device

Comment: Ok so any idea on how to implement a ContentProvider with JSON files? Android documentation says it can be done but all of their examples assume you're using an SQL database, which I'm not.

Comment: write a method to convert json data into a sqlite db! ,iterate through your json file for grabbing all required data (preferably in a hashmap ), create a sqlite db , write into the db!